# Parameters are passed as bytes, and I need them as strings. Looking for a cleaner way to accomplish this

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, base64

I am looking for a better way of handling an issue I am having. Essentially, I have a method that takes 2 parameters, formats the strings in a certain way, and base64 encodes that. The issue I am running into is that the parameters received are encoded as bytes, and I need to decode it then re-encode it before base64 encoding the string, which seems like a not very clean solution. For an example of my current code (which works) is below:

```
item = b64encode("{} and {}".format(first.decode('utf-8'), second.decode('utf-8')).encode('utf-8'))
```

If I don't decode `first` and `second`, then I run into an issue where the base64 encoded value is incorrect because `first` and `second` are bytes instead of raw strings.

Comment: writing a function for it, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decoding and encoding is only necessary because you want to call `str.format` in order to concatenate your first and second strings together. But if you concatenate them some other way, then you don't need to convert.

Unfortunately, the `bytes` type does not have a `.format` method, but there are other ways to put your bytes together. For instance, manual adding:

```
>>> first = b"foo"
>>> second = b"bar"
>>> base64.b64encode(first + b" and " + second)
b'Zm9vIGFuZCBiYXI='
```

... Or `.format`'s predecessor, percent-style formatting:

```
>>> base64.b64encode(b"%b and %b" % (first, second))
b'Zm9vIGFuZCBiYXI='
```